# Trouble With fcrackzip in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, 18.04, kali

So for the past two days I've been trying to figure this out by myself but I'm relatively inexperienced. My dad gave me a zip file that was password protected because he forgot the password and wanted into the file.

I'm trying to use fcrackzip to gain access but every time I run the command:

```
fcrackzip -u -D -p '/usr/share/wordlists/hash.txt' e.zip
```

the terminal tells me 'No such file or directory'. The problem is that the file is sitting right on the desktop. I don't know if this is down to running Ubuntu in a VM or if I'm cursed, but I've tried it in Ubuntu and a spin off distro (Zorin OS) and Kali Linux but none of the three have worked.

I even tried John The Ripper but now I'm at the end of my rope. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you have the wrong path to your file? First run `cd ~/Desktop` and then run your command...